# shortcuts don't work with a non-english keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

It seems to be an unresolved issue that you shortcuts with special characters are not supported when using non-english keyboards. I encounter the problem a lot in google chrome or MS OneNote.

For instance, {Ctrl}{+} is used in Google chrome to zoom in. To produce this outcome, I have to type {Ctrl}{Shift}{1} on my (Swiss German) keyboard. Shortcuts don't work, whenever I have to insert an additional {shift}.

I tried to circumvent the problem by using the following AutoHotKey Code:

```
^9::
Send,{Ctrl Down}{U+0x2B}{Ctrl Up}
Return
```

where {U+0x2B} is the Unicode for the "plus"-sign. Why doesn't this produced the intended outcome, i.e. enlarge my google chrome tab?

Unfortunately, I lack the technical knowledge to see why this does not work or how to fix it.

Comment: can't you also use `send {ctrl down}{+}{ctrl up}`? (which, btw, is the same like `send ^{+}`

Comment: @Blauhirn Yes, absolutely. None of these seem to work, though.

Comment: First of all what Blauhirn sent you does work. Secondly for the Unicode syntax leave the "0x". It's just {U+2B}. Nevertheless sending characters using that syntax may not produce the same behavior in your target application. So just stick with what Blauhirn gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your advice! You are right that my way was unnecessarily complicated.

`send ^{+}` did not work at my machine, but `Send, ^{NumpadAdd}` works fine.